# Unity Tweak Tool not working properly

Tags: unity, launcher, tweak

The whole Unity section and the system section (desktop icons won't appear on the desktop). It doesn't work. The window manager and appearance seem to be working, the launcher isn't showing up no matter where I position it.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity Tweak Tool 0.07